# MySQL - Schema is not valid & No mapping specified for instances of..... (etc.)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, linq, entity-framework-4

When I run the *.svc file in my solution to test the Web Service using the WCF Test Client in Visual Studio 2010 I get the following error:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
emp.msl(3,4) : error 2062: No mapping specified for instances of the EntitySet and AssociationSet in the EntityContainer empEntities.
```

If I right click on emp.edmx in the Model Browser > Generate Database from Model... > click Finish. Then click on the *.svc file and click run I get the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I can circle back to the first error by doing the following:

1. Right click on emp.edmx in the Model Browser > Update Model from Database...
2. Refresh the Tables, Views, and Stored Procedures
3. Right click on both *.tt files in the Solution Explorer > click Run Custom Tool for both files
4. Right click on the *.edmx file in the Solution Explorer > click Run Custom Tool
5. Left click on the *.svc file, then run, invoke anything and I get the original error.

Also, the database has been edited and I am trying to align the app's schema to the db's schema, more or less. The app was working before someone edited the db.

The app uses linq & MySQL to query the database which then presents the table on SharePoint for people to view, not edit.

I have reviewed the following posts and have gotten nowhere:

- [Why am I getting this error: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - Entity1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667355/why-am-i-getting-this-error-no-mapping-specified-for-the-following-entityset-as)
- [How do I correctly set an association between two objects in the Entity Framework 4 Entitydesigner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700637/how-do-i-correctly-set-an-association-between-two-objects-in-the-entity-framewor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My manager helped me out. I posted the question on here because he was swamped with work.

The app I was working on was purchased by a company and the company I work for services them. The developer at their company has a bad habit of changing schemas & dbs on the fly, so, he changed the id numbers I was using. I started using different functions and it worked.

I was correct to right click on emp.edmx in the Model Browser > Generate Database from Model... > click Finish, because that corrected some broken field mappings.

Although now I have a different problem.... but, this post seems to be dead so I won't bother throwing it on here.