# entity framework error after attached .mdf file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I attached an `.mdf` file in SQL Server 2008  and used that database for my entity framework database first project. Below is the error I got

> Exception Details: System.Data.MappingException: Schema specified is not valid.
>   Error 2062: No mapping specified for instances of the EntitySet and AssociationSet in the EntityContainer"

I tried this link: [How do I correctly set an association between two objects in the Entity Framework 4 Entitydesigner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700637/how-do-i-correctly-set-an-association-between-two-objects-in-the-entity-framewor)

but it did not work for me. can anyone help me what can be the problem.

thanks,
michaeld

Comment: have u tried deleting tables from designer and regenerating the model?

Comment: If you are creating the model from the database why are you trying to add entities relations?

Answer (score 0):

This exception usually occures if you have an entity in your model which doesn't mapped to a table (or an object) into the Database.

If you want that your project just starts debugging, Remove all entities from your model, Right-click in model designer and choose `Update model from database`

If you have an entity which it supposed to be mapped to a table into database, you should create a relative table in database, and map your entity to that table. You also can ghange your approach from db-first to code-first and enable migrations so that EF updates your db according to your model.

If you have an entity and you want to map it to a stored procedure in your db, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896279.aspx)